# font.drawString() cause a black screen when not ending in a string

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I have finally figured out how to display text on the screen using Slick-Util. I have however run into another issue. Whenever I try to display something like the amount of exp required to level up in my game:

```
font.drawString(10, 10, exp + " / " + expNeeded);
```

Using the coordinates 10, 10 as an example (not the issue). Whenever I have something like this where the String parameter ends with a variable, my screen is just black and all that displays is the text. If I did something like this:

```
font.drawString(10, 10, exp + " / " + expNeeded + "a");
```

That would work just fine. It seems that as long as there is at least one character at the end of the parameter it will work. I cannot just use a space and I do not know why this is happening.

NOTE: This game is 2D (In case this info is needed)

With the text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWBMH.png Without the text (how its supposed to look): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMNgf.png

**Package Explorer (With pastebin links):**

Game Test 2

src

```
com.kaperly.common

  [Game.java][1]

com.kaperly.objects

  [ObjectBullet.java][2]

  [ObjectEnemy.java][3]

  [ObjectExpBar.java][4]

  [ObjectPlayer.java][5]
```

Comment: Is font a Graphics object?

Comment: public static UnicodeFont font = new UnicodeFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));

Comment: Is it important to you that you use a UnicodeFont? Would you be willing to try something else?

Comment: I am up for anything, UnicodeFont was just the way I found first.

Comment: Alright one more question, is this an applet or a JFrame?

Comment: I am using LWJGL. And I have no plans to make any applets.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here:

1. First off your game loop goes in the order of:

   `render();
    logic();`

   This is not the correct order of events for a game loop, it should be the other way around. In addition to this you have some rendering code inside your logic method. *All* of your code for rendering should be inside your render function.
2. Finally if you must have a string at the end of that drawString method for it to work, then why not declare it like this:

   `font.drawString(10, 10, exp + " / " + expNeeded + "");`

   It will not look any different to you or the player, and it should work like expected as long as the string is drawn first.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have updated the post with pastebin links to almost all of the source code. Your answer did not work for me.